# Setting style for Python docstrings in lstinputlisting environment

Tags: listings, highlighting, code, comments

I am using the [listings](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings) package for source code in my LaTeX document. I am trying to set the style for docstrings in the [Python](https://www.python.org/) programming language:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\lstset{
    language=Python,
    showstringspaces=false,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    commentstyle=\itshape
}

\begin{lstlisting}
# This is a comment
""" This is a docstring """
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

As you can see if you compile this code, setting the `commentstyle` does not change the style of docstrings. How can I set the style of docstrings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working from section 3.2 of [the listings documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf), use the `morecomment` parameter to use triple quotes as delimiters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\lstset{
    language=Python,
    showstringspaces=false,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    commentstyle=\itshape,
    morecomment=[s]{"""}{"""},
}

\begin{lstlisting}
# This is a comment
""" This is a docstring """
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]